# Category next page link not working

Tags: categories

When I go to a category page and it lists the posts that are in that category, it lists 10 per page. At the bottom of the page it has the link for next page, but that link returns a 404 error.

The first page of the category which works fine is
http://mcisc.org.au/tourism/?cat=27

But when I click next, or directly on a page number, the url is
http://mcisc.org.au/tourism/?cat=27page/2

I can't figure out how the page 2 link should be formatted or where to change the incorrect format that it is using.

Any help greatly appreciated.

Brendan

Comment: Share the template code where it is coming from!

Comment: Impossible to answer this without seeing your code. Somewhere you, your theme or a plugins is building paginated URL's wrongly. That is the code you should be posting

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**I may be jumping to a conclusion without seeing your code first.**

But I believe this may simply be because the way have your permalinks setup.

If you go to your `dashboard` then `settings->permalinks` and change the option to anything other than `Plain`.

Comment: Answers should not be based on pure guess work. In this instance, your guesswork is way out and does not even remotely answers the question. I would advice you to rather post comments and try to get clarity about the issue than to just blindingly posting totally incorrect answers

Comment: Yep, that did the trick, changed the permalink setting and all good now.